# Remove all flow file attributes except the ones explicitly defined

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I want to remove all attributes from a given flow file except the ones I explicitly define to keep.

Given the following sample flow file attributes:

```
name: aaa
Place: bbb
Host: ccc
JsonAttribute: {
    "A": "a",
    "B": "b"
}
data: ddd
```

And I want to keep **Host** and **JsonAttribute** only.

Thus, the resulting flow file attributes should be:

```
Host: ccc
JsonAttribute: {
    "A": "a",
    "B": "b"
}
```

How can I achieve this using the standard processors NiFi provides?

#### *renaming* the attributes

Is it possible to rename the attributes using the same procedure? E.g. I would like to keep the attributes like above but rename **JsonAttribute** into **customName**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *UpdateAttribute* processor does not only allow to add / set flow file attributes but also enables you to delete existing attributes from a flow file.

To do so you have to pass a regular expression matching all attributes you want to remove to the property `Delete Attributes Expression`.

In your case you can use a [negative look-around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/3160089) to match every attribute other than the ones you want to keep.

```
^((?!Host)(?!JsonAttribute).)*$
```

So no additional processor is needed.

#### keeping Host attribute, moving JsonAttribute to a different attribute name

You should be able to also achieve the second behaviour using only a single *UpdateAttribute* processor.

Simply add a property, e.g. `customName`, to the processor and reference the old attribute using the NiFi **E**xpression **L**anguage:

```
${JsonAttribute}
```

In that case you may also simplify your deletion regex to also delete the JsonAttribute flow file attribute:

```
^((?!Host).)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

AttributesToJSON Processor can filter data you don't need.You can set Attributes Regular Expression in this Processor.

Comment: is there any way to customize the json name i.e.,instead of JsonAttributes: {"A":"a","B":"b"} --> customName:{"A":"a","B":"b"}

Answer (score 1):

In the `invokehttp` processor there is an `Attributes to Send` property where you could define attributes to be used in request.

So you don't need to filter out attributes in another processor.

Comment: by setting Attributes to Send --> JsonAttribute and given a try, but i am getting 400 bad request...

Comment: That's another question. Read about httprequest - it sends to server flow file content as a body and attributes as http headers.